# combining three models in to one model using function

Tags: r

I have a random forest model in R for three countries. Each country features are same. however for each country there are different outlier treament and missing treatment. can i combine the three into one. but the outlier treatment and missing treatemnt should be done basis on the country level. and finally running a sepeatate random forest model for the three country.

My problem is that i have three different models and it consume a lot of time to run separately. can i combine all the three model into some sort of one model using a  function and i can get the output in one sheet with its respective country flag

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 
5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 
5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 
4.6, 5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 
5, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 
6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6, 5.4, 6, 6.7, 
6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7, 
6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 
5.7, 5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 
6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 
6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 
4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 
2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 
2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 
2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 
3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 
3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 
2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 
3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 
3), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 
1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 
1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 
3.5, 4.2, 4, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 
4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 4.1, 
6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 
5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6, 4.8, 
4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 
5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 
1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 
1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 
1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 
1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 
1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 
1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), 
    country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Africa", "India"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-150L))


africa<-x%>%filter(country=="Africa")
India<-x%>%filter(country=="India")

#Model for India

India<-India %>%
  mutate(Petal.Length= case_when(
    Petal.Length >= Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
    TRUE ~ Petal.Width))

India<-India%>%select(-c(country))

set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(India), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
train_I <- India[ind==1,]
test_I <- India[ind==2,]

rf <- randomForest(
  Species ~ .,
  data=train_I
)

pred_inda = predict(rf, test_I)

#Model for africa


africa<-africa %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width= case_when(
    Sepal.Width >= Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width,
    TRUE ~ Petal.Width))

africa<-africa%>%select(-c(country))

set.seed(1234)
ind1 <- sample(2, nrow(africa), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
train_a <- africa[ind==1,]
test_a <- africa[ind==2,]

rf1 <- randomForest(
  Species ~ .,
  data=train_a
)

pred_africa = predict(rf, test_a)
```

Comment: Create custom function combining different treatments with if condition limiting each treatment by country. Create a list from the dataframes of the countries. 3. Use lapply with the put object as the list created and function as the custom function.

Comment: I have added a sample data and its respective model. can you help in creating a custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps that are repeated in "if" function can be avoided, bu operating them prior to "if" condition.

```
#Creating a list out of the data frame by country
lst<- split(x, x$country)

#Custom function 
fun1 <- function(data) {
  if(unique(data$country)=="India"){
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(Petal.Length= case_when(
        Petal.Length >= Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
          TRUE ~ Petal.Width))
    df = data%>%select(-c(country))
    set.seed(1234)
    s1 = sample(2, nrow(df), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
    train = df[s1==1,]
    test = df[s1==2,]
    rf = randomForest(
        Species ~ .,
        data=train)
  }
  if(unique(data$country)=="Africa"){
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(Petal.Length= case_when(
        Petal.Length >= Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
        TRUE ~ Petal.Width))
    df = data%>%select(-c(country))
    set.seed(1234)
    s1 = sample(2, nrow(df), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.3))
    train = df[s1==1,]
    test = df[s1==2,]

    rf = randomForest(
      Species ~ .,
      data=train)

  }    
  predict(rf, test)
}

out <- lapply(lst, fun1)
```

**Output:**

```
> out
$Africa
         5         14         16         26         28         29         36         39         40         50 
    setosa     setosa     setosa versicolor versicolor versicolor  virginica versicolor versicolor versicolor 
        58         60         61         72         74 
 virginica versicolor  virginica  virginica  virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

$India
         5         14         16         26         28         29         39         40         60         61 
    setosa     setosa     setosa versicolor versicolor versicolor  virginica versicolor  virginica  virginica 
        72 
 virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```